# How to get the date of last commit of repo?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, github, fetch

Example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "sha": "0bf21a1dc1c03f11bb44ac32a65c17b5857b020c",
    "node_id": "MDyODE2MY6Q29tbWl0NzYGJmMjFjYzE3YjUwM2YxMDk6MWJiNDRhYzMyYTFkYzFhNjU4NTdiMDIwYw==",
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        "name": "Max Mustermann",
        "email": "max@mustermann.at",
        "date": "2016-12-12T19:56:46Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "GitHub",
        "email": "noreply@github.com",
        "date": "2016-12-12T19:56:46Z"
      },
      "message": "Update README.md", ...
```

**How do I get the date of *commit -> author -> date* in javascript?** 
My test:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/schletz/3KanalAdWandler/commits", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result.commit.author.date))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

What I get: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'author')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result`appears to be an array, so you'll have to include the array index. `console.log(result[0].commit.author.date)`.